# View inside a Fragment isn't destroyable?

Tags: android-fragments, android

i have a problem with the android Fragment class. I already implemented a FragmentStatePagerAdapter etc. Now my problem is the following: I added my own View-class to each "LSDataFragment":

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle args = getArguments();   
    mConnection = ((WorkActivity) this.getActivity()).getConnection(args
            .getInt(ARG_OBJECT));

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager, container, false);

    mView = new LSDataView(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),(WorkActivity) this.getActivity());
    update();

    return rootView;
}
public void update(){

    final RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pagerMainLayout);     
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

            mainLayout.addView(mView, params);
    mainLayout.invalidate();
    //doesn't work outside the uiThread?!
    ((WorkActivity) this.getActivity()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            mainLayout.addView(mView, params);
            mainLayout.invalidate();
        }
    });

}
```

But when i remove the Fragment from my FragmentStatePagerAdapter, the LSDataView mView is remaining on the screen, and not destroyed (wtf):

```
        for(Connection c : WorkActivity.this.mConnections){
            if(c.getHandler() == handler)
                WorkActivity.this.mConnections.remove(c);
        }
        WorkActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mCollectionPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

        });
```